# How to access the anonymous inner class using ASM framework

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

For example, I need to aceess the information in run() after the code compiled.

```
Class A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //something
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I have extended the ASM ClassVisitor, how should I do to access the information in an anonymous inner class.

```
public class MyClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {

    public MyClassVisitor(final ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature,
            String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        if (cv != null) {
            cv.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void visitInnerClass(String name, String outerName, String innerName, int access) {
        //how should I do to access the information in an anonymous inner class
        super.visitInnerClass(name, outerName, innerName, access);
    }
}
```

Comment: An anonymous inner class has a name like MyClass$1. The suffix is incremented at each inner class.

Comment: I mean, how to use the ASM framework to access the information in an anonymous inner class. Thanks!

Comment: maybe provide a simple example ?

Comment: I hava modified the problem and provide the example.@ Aimee Borda

Comment: The method `visitInnerClass` is probably not want you want. It only gives you names and access info. You'll need to override `visitMethod` to access method information. Use `MyClassVisitor` with class name like `A$1`.

Comment: @dejvuth: Thank you! I have solved the problem. Thank you all, you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You know that the name of anonymous inner class after compiled like `Main$1`. Based on this fact, we can access the method information by override `visitMethod`.

The code is as follows.

```
public class MyClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {

    private String ownerClassName;

    public MyClassVisitor(final ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature,
            String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        if (cv != null) {
            cv.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
            ownerClassName = name;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
            String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature,
                exceptions);
        //the name of anonymous inner class after compiled was like this: Main$1
        String[] array = ownerClassName.split("$");
        boolean isNumber = false;
        if(array.length > 1){
            isNumber = array[array.length - 1].matches("[0-9]+");
        }
        //if it's an anonymous inner class and the method was not construction method
        if(isNumber && !name.equals("<init>")){
            //return my custom MethodVisitor to parse the method information
            return new MyMethodVisitor(mv);
        }
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Comment: The name `Main$1` could be an anonymous inner class inside a class `Main` or inside a method `main` or a top level class having the explicit name `Main$1`, you don’t know. But it’s irrelevant as you are not checking for `Main` anyway. Btw, it’s unclear why you repeat this class name check for every method instead of doing it once for the entire class, i.e. right in the `visit` method. If you really want to know whether the class has been declared within a method, you have to watch for the [`EnclosingMethod ` attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.7)…

Comment: @Holger: I have been aware of the problem, thanks for the warning!